# C# Dictionary <of String, String> как проверить, содержит ли колекция null value?

Tags: c#, словари

Собственно вопрос в теме. 
C# Dictionary  как проверить, содержит ли колекция null  value ?

Comment: подробнее, что это значит? `содержит ли колекция null value`

Comment: в Java это String k = null, содержит ли такие value словарь, где ключ есть, а значение null

Comment: `Dictionary<T, K>` - это не строка. Потому проверить, равно ли оно пустой строке вы не можете.

Comment: но K, это строка. есть же метод ContainsValue, куда передаю строку и получаю содержит ли коллекция такое value

Comment: либо пробежаться по всем ключам и сравнить значения, либо использовать LINQ, что-то вроде: `var dictonary = new Dictonary<string,string>(); dictonary.Add(...);...;dictonary.where(d=>d.Value==null).ToList();`, не уверен что синтаксис правильный, но мысль такая.

Comment: @Monomax ключи в словаре не могут быть null

Comment: то есть вам надо `myDictionary.Values.Contains(null)`?

Comment: @tym32167 ключи нет, а вот значение принадлежащее ключу, может.

Comment: @Monomax чтобы проверить значения не надо бегать по ключам же. Или я вас не понял

Comment: Всем спасибо, @tym32167. немного не проснулся и теперь стыдно. да, Contains(null) отлично работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод `ContainsValue`. Например

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        d.Add( "null", null );
        d.Add( "not_null", "not_null" );

        Console.WriteLine( d.ContainsValue( null ) );

        d.Remove( "null" );

        Console.WriteLine( d.ContainsValue( null ) );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
True
False
```

Comment: +1 от меня, я что то совсем забыл про этот метод, он гораздо лучше, чем `myDictionary.Values.Contains(null)`, так как не аллоцирует дополнительную память.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic.Values.Any(val => val == null)
```

Если есть хоть одно значение равное null вернётся true